# AVAudioPlayer numberOfLoops not working as expected when setting currentTime property

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

I am facing an issue in looping a single audio track with AVAudioPlayer while setting the currentTime property.

If I won't do any operations on the currentTime property, the looping is proper and it's playing the audio file the same number of times as given in numberOfLoops, but if I do operations on currentTime by setting it duration of audio file by decrementing 1 the audio file is always starts even numberOfLoops are completed.

Please check the code below.

```
@interface AVAudioPlayerInterface ()<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
        @property (strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer;
@end

@implementation AVAudioPlayerInterface
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        [self downloadAudioContent];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) downloadAudioContent
{
    NSString *musicFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aleale" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *completeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicFilePath];
    NSError *err=nil;
    self.musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:completeUrl fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3 error:&err];
 }
-(void)playAtSpecifiedTime:(NSUInteger)pointOfPlayTime
{
    self.musicPlayer.currentTime = pointOfPlayTime;
}
-(void)play
{
    [self.musicPlayer play];
}
-(void)playLoop:(NSUInteger)numberOfTimes
{
    NSLog(@"Number of times to loop %lu",numberOfTimes);
    self.musicPlayer.numberOfLoops=numberOfTimes;
}
@end
@interface ViewController ()
@property ( strong, nonatomic)  AVAudioPlayerInterface *audioPlayer;
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayerInterface alloc]init];
    self.currentVolume = 0.5;
    NSLog(@"View loaded");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (IBAction)playSong:(id)sender {
// Following is sequense i am executing
    [self.audioRecord play];
    [self.audioRecord playLoop:1];
    [self.audioRecord playAtSpecifiedTime:200];//my audio file is 201 seconds so ending-1
    [self.audioRecord playAtSpecifiedTime:200];
    //At this point the audio file is still playing irrespective of number of calls on [self.audioRecord playAtSpecifiedTime:200];
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What i understood from your code are you trying to stop the current audio cycle.Stop the current loop and use [self.audioRecord playAtSpecifiedTime:200];

Comment: I have a requirement to loop the selected audio to run multiple number of times, to achieve that while playing the audio I am moving the seek position of audio to end of the file(Doing this part from UI) for verifying the next loop will run or not, but in my case even my loop is defined the audio looping is continuously playing when setting seek to end for every repetition of audio

Comment: Better stop the current loop and change the current time           [self.audioRecord stop]                               
    [self.audioRecord playAtSpecifiedTime:200];

Comment: By your suggestions i made the changes and observe the behavior, before seek we need to mark current loop to 0 and seek to approriate position and apply new current loop, so that last updated current loop works as expected

Comment: Thanks balagurubaran for your suggestion, but I have a query on the relation between currentLoop and currentTime properties and its behaviour?